# Put data received from a website in map view

Tags: ios, swift3

with the function getURL(),I receive data from the web site successfully and I wanted to put latiltude  and longitude in a mapView but I find an error that type of type CLL location not compatible with a string,
I wanted to put at least my own location and see it in map view but I didn't find any thing in the map.
can you help me?

```
/* func getURL(){
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://gpsforanimal.herokuapp.com/positions.json")!)
 request.httpMethod = "GET"
 let session = URLSession.shared
 session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
 if error != nil {
 print(error!.localizedDescription)
 }
 guard let data = data else { return }
 do {
 //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Article object
 let realData = try JSONDecoder().decode([gps].self, from: data)
 //print(realData)
 if let data = realData.last {
 print(data.latitude!)

 print(data.longitude!)
 print(data.created_at)
 print(data.updated_at)
 }
 } catch let jsonError {
 print(jsonError)
 }
 }.resume()
 }*/
/* struct gps : Codable{
 var id = Int()
 var longitude  : String?
 var latitude : String?
 var created_at = String()
 var updated_at = String()
 var url = String()

 init(){
 self.id = Int()
 self.longitude = String()
 self.latitude  = String()
 self.created_at = String()
 self.updated_at = String()
 self.url = String()
 }
 } */


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    map.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    // map.showsUserLocation = true
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    //user location stuff
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.719913, longitude: 10.718982)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true

    func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation])
    {///
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting String to Float?

Comment: Yes  I do this   var lat : Float!
        var long : Float!
         lat  = Float(data.latitude)
         long = Float(data.longitude)
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)

Comment: and it gives me this error

Comment: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Float' with an argument list of type '(String?)'

Comment: Try: let long = Float(data.longitude!) or let long = Float(data.longitude ?? "0.0")